# How do I make a wrapped flexbox's content grow equally?

Tags: css, flexbox

In a flexbox where wrapping is enabled, the `flex-grow` property doesn't behave quite the way I'd like: the growth is determined row by row. Here are two samples, one without `flex-grow`, one with `flex-grow`:

```css
.container {
  border: dotted 1px green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}
.container > div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container.grow > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>

<div class="container grow"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

I'd like all child `div` elements to have the same width, as in the first container, but still allow for that width to expand to fill the container. In other words, I'd like all child `div` elements to have the size that's used in the first row of the second container. Does flexbox have any option that allows that? If not, does CSS provide any other alternative?

Note: I'm using fixed widths here only for a simple example. Both the container and the child width are dynamic in my real page.

[Chris Wright's Flexbox adventures](https://chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/flexbox-adventures/) shows something that seems to work (look for "Source ordering"), but isn't a general solution. It uses `@media` with `min-width` to dynamically alter the width of the contained items (setting `flex-basis` as a percentage). But making this work requires knowing when the content will wrap. I'm trying to use `flex-wrap` so that I don't have to worry about it, so that I can let the browser make that determination for me.

Comment: How did you define the width of the elements in your real page? Using percentages or do you want the content to decide the actual width?

Comment: @NicoO The content should determine the minimum width, and therefore the wrapping. The actual width may be (and normally is) larger than the minimum width.

Comment: So basically you want to have all flex-items to have the jet unknown width of the first flex-item, which may be 1% to 100% depending on it's content?

Comment: @NicoO Sort of, although 1% should never be possible because of `flex-grow`. Using the five columns I have here, if the wrapping gives me one row, I want each item to have a width of 20%. If I get two rows, I want each item to have a with of 33 1/3 %, even if that leaves the second row unfilled. If I get three rows, I want each item to have a width of 50%. If I get five rows, I want each item to have a width of 100%. In other words, I want `flex-grow` to grow the items, but I want them to grow equally across the full container, not row by row.

Comment: I think you will have to use javascript for this :/ even it's not pretty, you could do something like getting the parent container, get it's first child and it's total children, then calculate (widthOfFirstItem/ContainerWidth) to get the number of rows and then apply a new `flex-basis` property for all the children. You could prepare a class for each possible use case (like `.three-rows`, `.four-rows > .items { flex-basis: 25% }` etc.)

Comment: Heh, that's ugly, but yeah, that should at least work, thanks. I hope to get a better answer than that, though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's possible to get this working by creating filler items that have the same width as the actual content, but a height of zero so that they become invisible after the last content row. Enough filler items have to be created to definitely fill up the last content row, but creating more than required is harmless. I've created as many filler items as content items.

It gets a bit tricky, because those filler items *could* end up on the very first row if the container is large enough. Using an additional layer of `div` elements, and giving them a minimum width of 20% (based on five content boxes), forces them on the second line in that case.

Animated demo (in Chrome and Firefox, anyway):

```css
.container {
  border: dotted 1px green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation: resize 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes resize {
  0%, 100% { width: 120px; }
  50% { width: 1000px; }
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-width: 20%;
}
.container-item {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container-filler {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><div class="container-item"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-item"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-item"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-item"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-item"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-filler"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-filler"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-filler"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-filler"></div></div>
  <div><div class="container-filler"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice workaround and demo. But the more I think about, I come to the conclusion, that this not really, what you described in your question. This more: *How to have flex-items have the same width across multiple rows.* As the width of the first child is not relative to the solution of the problem. All you want is a grid of equal items. I think there is a simpler solution to this problem which I will think about.

Comment: @NicoO I'm not entirely happy with it, which is why I didn't accept my own answer yet. :) In my question, I wrote "I'd like all child div elements to have the same width, as in the first container, but still allow for that width to expand to fill the container." Isn't that exactly what I did here? I make sure all child div items have the same width, and still allow that width to expand to fill the container. Sorry if I didn't get the question across correctly. If you have a better / simpler solution, I'd very much like to see that!

Comment: To be honest this is driving me mad at the moment ;) This must be possible. You really don't need to apologize as I failed to understand the question correctly. When i stumble upon a solution i will make sure to post it.